# Achieve smooth transition in a div having position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have a popup in a map container. The position of the popup changes depending upon the position of marker to which it is attached. The css applied is:

```
#popup{
 opacity:1,
 bottom:100px,
 left:200px
}
```

Here, the value of bottom and left is changing dynamically through javascript and it changes rapidly.
When the position changes the popup directly jumps to the location and does not slide. What needs to be done so that it slides and does not directly jump to the position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add the `transition` css property.

```
#popup{
  opacity:1,
  bottom:100px,
  left:200px
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `transition:all .2s linear;` for smooth transition OR separately `transition:left .2s linear, bottom .2s linear;`

```js
$('#popup').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('added');
});
```

```css
#popup{
 opacity:1;
 bottom:100px;
 left:200px;
 transition:all .2s linear;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:red;
 position:absolute;
}

#popup.added{
 opacity:1;
 bottom:10px;
 left:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
  Hi
</div>
```